# How can i resize images in Tkinter using PIL module

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i got this code and i get this error:
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'
I have also tried `rgrapg = Image.open("risinggrap.jpg")` and i get this error: _tkinter.TclError: image "" doesn't exist

````
   rgraph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("risinggrap.jpg"))
   rgraph = rgraph.resize((200,250),Image.ANTIALIAS)
   photoLabe = Label(x, image=rgraph)```
````

Comment: You have to call `.resize()` on the `Image`, and *then* convert it to a `PhotoImage` so that Tkinter can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the image first, resize it, then cast it into `ImageTk.PhotoImage`. Here is a working example that goes like so:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

x = tk.Tk()

# 1. load image
image = Image.open("risinggrap.jpg")

# 2. resize it
image = image.resize((200, 250), Image.ANTIALIAS)

# 3. cast it into ImageTk.PhotoImage
rgraph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

photoLabel = tk.Label(x, image = rgraph)
photoLabel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
x.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes i've done it ```rgraph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("risinggrap.jpg"))```

Comment: But then, you tried to resize `rgraph`... you should resize the image itself

Comment: i tried this ```lobal rgraph
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("risinggrap.jpg"))
    image = image.resize((200,250),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    rgraph = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    photoLabe = Label(x, image=rgraph)
    photoLabe.grid(row=3, column=4,rowspan=3)``` and i got this AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'

Comment: Please, could you do exactly as my answer? in my answer I resized `image` not `rgraph` because `rgraph` can NOT be resized.

Comment: i did it isn't it the same expect i used ``` ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("risinggrap.jpg"))``` instead of Image.open beacause i get an error if i use it

Comment: You can't use `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("risinggrap.jpg"))`. That's literally the problem. What is the error that you get when you use `image.open()`??

Comment: i tried this ```global rgraph
    image = Image.open("risinggrap.jpg")
    image=image.resize((300,300),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    rgrpah = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    photoLabe = Label(x,image = rgrpah)
    photoLabe.grid(row=3, column=4,rowspan=3)``` i think it works because the place for image is created but there is no image showing

Comment: yeah it now worked i had to do a global image and global rgraph because i was inside a function thank you for your help

Comment: where is that i'm not finding it